# Override Kernel Method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, kernel, overriding

I'm working through a programming exercise where I have to override the `rand` kernel method in Ruby.

I've tried

```
module Kernel
  def rand(max=0)
    return 0
  end
end
```

And I've tried

```
class Random
  def rand(max=0)
   return 0
  end
end
```

neither seem to work. How should I go about doing this?

Edit:

I realized the bug. I should have written

```
module Kernel
  def self.rand(max=0)
    0
  end
end
```

I was not calling just plain rand() but Kernel::rand() and it seems that calling it that way requires to override with `self` in front.  Can anyone explain why that is? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`module` should be written in lower case

```
module Kernel
  def rand(max=0)
    return 0
  end
end

10.times { print rand(100) } # => 0000000000
```

Also, you can skip `return` keyword here

Comment: I did write it in lower case , I just made that typo here and I'm still not getting zero

Comment: @Manny_G ok, well, show us what you are trying to do, what you receive and what you expect to receive by editing a question. (ie i showed by `10.times { print rand(100) }` that `Kernel#rand` was overridden, show what is wrong in your case)

Answer (score 1):

You were actually on a good path!

The only thing you missed is the keyword `self` because rand is a class mehotd, not an instance method. You can read more about it here: http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

```
module Kernel
  def self.rand(max=0)
    return 0
  end
end
```

Good luck!